# Como fazer um slider?

Tags: html, css

Como posso fazer com que os quadrados fiquem em apenas uma linha, gerando um *scroll* horizontal, onde eu possa navegar para os outros blocos deslizando para esquerda ou direita.

```css
    .box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .box:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
    .box:nth-child(2) { background: orangered; }
    .box:nth-child(3) { background: purple; }
    .box:nth-child(4) { background: yellow; }
    .box:nth-child(5) { background: green; }
    .box:nth-child(6) { background: black; }
    .box:nth-child(7) { background: orange; }
    .box:nth-child(8) { background: orangered; }
    .box:nth-child(9) { background: purple; }
    .box:nth-child(10) { background: yellow; }
    .box:nth-child(11) { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class=itens>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: isso precisa ser feito no div com o style "itens". se adicionar um display deve funcionar: `.itens{   display: inline-flex;}`

Answer (score 1):

Na classe itens coloca `display:flex` e `overflow-x: auto`, nesse exemplo eu limitei o `width` em `350px` apenas para vc poder ver o *scroll* aparecer.

Deixei tb uns comentes no código abaixo para ajudar

```css
.itens {
  overflow-x: auto; /*ativa o scroll horizontal caso necessário*/
  display: flex; /*coloca os elementos em linha*/
  width: 350px; /*limita a largura do container*/
}
.box{
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
.box:nth-child(2) { background: orangered; }
.box:nth-child(3) { background: purple; }
.box:nth-child(4) { background: yellow; }
.box:nth-child(5) { background: green; }
.box:nth-child(6) { background: black; }
.box:nth-child(7) { background: orange; }
.box:nth-child(8) { background: orangered; }
.box:nth-child(9) { background: purple; }
.box:nth-child(10) { background: yellow; }
.box:nth-child(11) { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class=itens>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```